# How do I get Custom Post Types to show up on Archive pages without breaking my Custom Fields below?

Tags: php, wordpress, acfpro

I have added the following code below my custom post type function in my functions.php file but once I've added it, it seems to break all my ACF custom fields below it ( some fields that are in the footer ).

Is there a way to fix this so that stops happening?

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
    function query_post_type($query) {
      if( is_category() ) {
        $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
        if($post_type)
            $post_type = $post_type;
        else
            $post_type = array('nav_menu_item', 'post', 'conditions', 'product-reviews', 'conversations', 'experts', 'custom_fields'); 

        $query->set('post_type', $post_type);
        return $query;

        } 
    }
```

Comment: What is your code supposed to do?

Comment: @rank - The code above adds the CPT posts to the archive pages. Without it they don't show up they are, only regular posts do.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to change the main query instead of using a custom query for getting posts and custom posts? as the docs say, it is not recommended if not absolutly necessary https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_query/

Comment: @rank - Well I was following a tutorial [link] (https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-categories-to-a-custom-post-type-in-wordpress/) on WP Beginner. I am open to doing it any way really, I just need my custom posts to show up on archive pages and to not break my custom fields.

Comment: 1. In your code, get rid of the ` 'custom_fields' ` it is nothing you need. The custom fields are part of your post type, you do not need to query them as post type.   If still not working 2. You can create a custom page template and make a custom query in it. I can show you how. Or do you need to keep it in the archive.php of your posts because of some reason?

Comment: @rank - I tried removing that and it didn't have an effect on the problem unfortunately. I would ideally like the to keep it in the archive.php template because I want my custom post types to show up alongside my regular posts when categories they are both tagged in are selected.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix this by amending my code to the following:

```
function custom_post_type_cat_filter($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_category()) {
      $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'conditions', 'product-reviews', 'conversations' ) );
    }
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','custom_post_type_cat_filter');
```